# Is there any data missing?

Tags: networking, network-programming

Here is some code quoted from Douglas.E.Comer's < Computer Networks and Internets > 4th edition. This program will send back any data it received.

```
...
while((len = recv(conn, buff, BUFFERSIZE,0)) >0) // receive data
        send(conn, buff, len, 0); // send it back
...
```

I am wondering, what if some data arrived when the code is executing in send(..) function, will it miss that data? Because the recv() function is not being executed. If no data is missed, where is the data kept? And by whom?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incoming data is buffered by the system until the *next* time the `recv()` function is called. This data that hasn't been read yet is stored in buffers inside the operating system and not inside your application. You will not "miss" incoming data using a loop like this.

Comment: Thanks Greg. So there're actually 2 type of buffers. My application's buffer and the OS's buffer. If there's too much data, could the OS's buffer be flooded? What happens then?

Comment: If your receiving application doesn't read enough data fast enough, then the OS will tell the *sending* machine to stop sending more data. In turn, the sending machine's operating system will have its own outgoing data buffers to hold data passed by `send()` from the sending application, and if *those* fill up, then the sending application will block in its calls to `send()`.

Comment: So it is all properly arranged by the OS or library method such as send(). And it seems we just need to care about our programming logic to use the infrastructure properly.

Answer (score 1):

Every socket has a associated memory buffer where the data is being buffered, when you call recv API the data is read from buffer if some data is present in buffer other wise the call wait till some data is available in socket buffer.

Comment: Thanks Ankur. Please see my reply to Greg Hewgill.

Comment: Your understanding is correct i.e. you just need to focus on your application logic. TCP was build to assure packets delivery. I am not sure if this will be the same case as in a UDP socket